# Set Window background as image from drive on runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Images shows in designer but when ran as debug in vs2013 it gives error:
also if exe ran directly with image in same folder.

```
information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '12' and line position '10'.
```

The error is bcoz it cant find the image. also in xaml view when hover the image sorce it says:

```
project file expected in c:\user\bsienn\docs\vs2013\project\wpf1\wpf1\image1.jpg
```

though the pic is indeed in that path and is available.

I want to add an image as background for form, I don't want to add the image in resource, bcoz i want the image to be changed when needed. I have placed the image with exe file also tried to place it in bin/debug and main application folder (wpf1/image1.jpg andalso wpf1/wpf1/image1.jpg).

here is the xaml code, please guide

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="image1.jpg"/>
</Window.Background>

App structure:
app.exe
image1.jpg
Desired outcome, form with background image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do as desired

XAML:

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush x:Name="MainFormBgrImg"/>
</Window.Background>
```

code behind:

```
BitmapImage bitimg = new BitmapImage();
bitimg.BeginInit();
bitimg.UriSource = new Uri(@""+AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"backgroundImg.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
bitimg.EndInit();
MainFormBgrImg.ImageSource = bitimg;
```

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory:
Returns current working directory from where where app ran from, i.e c:\users\admin\Desktop\

Answer (score 0):

Putting image in output folder won't make it available to your XAML.

You need to `add image in your project` and set it's `Build Action` to `Resource`.

Right click on added image in project -> Open Properties -> Set Build Action to Resource.

Comment: i know how to do that, But I don't want to add the image in resource, bcoz i want the image to be changed when needed. so i need to get the image from executable path, where the image resides

Comment: I am afraid then, it's not possible without adding image as a resource under project.

Comment: omg :( this is so weird that its not possible. but ty 4 ur time